# based on sql i had a table as below i want to insert a record where i want to delete a record?

Tags: sql

```
uid  | name |salary| deptno|
     |      |      |       |
1    | mani |5000  | 10    |
2    |nani  |6000  | 20    |
3    |phani |7000  | 30    |
```

Comment: We need a much better explanation to understand the problem.

Comment: if suppose i deleted a 2nd row record from the table and i want to insert new row record at that place of same table :)

Comment: @manideep siriki then we are talking about an `UPDATE`-Statement

Comment: Why do you want to re-use that uid? It's better to use a new uid for a new user. (Order makes no difference, it's unimportant.)

Comment: @manideep siriki Do you just want to delete a row and then insert a row. And the inserted row doesn't have to be where the previous row was deleted? Then you have to write a `DELETE` Statement and an other `INSERT`Statement

Answer (score 1):

you are describing an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE table
SET name = 'new name', salary = 1000, deptno = 50
WHERE uid = 2
```

But I'm not quite sure why to reuse the uid.

Comment: thanq for updating ur's thoughts but it is not correct.

Comment: @manideepsiriki, explain what's wrong with the answer. It seems to do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: if i delete the 2nd record from table i want to insert a new record at the place where i deleted the record of the table

Comment: Yes, you are exactely explaining what `Update` is for. replacing value(s) for specific row(s). So you dont need to `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

Comment: Well, if there are any foreign keys or triggers, the two versions may be different.